# Read one(2) hex-adresses from a string

Tags: arduino-mega

On a 2560 MEGA I use serial(0) and serial1.

Serial1 is connected to an AT-328P   (not an UNO but a single AT controller)

The 2560 use Interrupt (serialevent) and Serial1Event. 
Serial(0) is connected to the PC(USB) and is used to get commands that are planned to control both microcontrollers. And RX1 /TX1 (Serial1Event) is connected to the AT-328P .

I plan to use single letter Commands (eg. 'A' , 'B' .... 'Z') followed by a
delimiter (space or comma) again followed by 1 to 4 hexadecimals arguments.

EG:  "A 00,FFFF,AA,00"  or  "B,00,FFFF,33,00"  or "C 00,FF,FFFF,11"  or 
"D 01,0000,FFFF,01" or "E,00,0910,1"

Valid delimiters are space, comma and Carriage Return

First argument is the number of the controller (00 = 2560 / 01 = AT328P, second to 4'th is the actual command to the controller.

The problem is parsing the command line from the PC. The one I use is far to slow (I scan the inputBuffer char by char and take my desiscion from that) - much to slow.

Now I want to parse the inputBuffer BEFORE I check the command letter (saving time and get the param's before I go into the specific subroutine) but here I  am i trouble.  I dont' know how to convert the 4 (2) Ascii chars into a valid HEX (or INT) -value.

I have seen some code somewhere ( and naturally forgotten where) doing it, but the methods I have used till now is oldfashioned and (far) out of date, and I am not very good to C++ (but I wanna learn it), so  I will be ashamed showing it.

Can any one give me an idea how to proceed .

Thanks

Kris AKA Snestrup2016

Comment: You wrote “_The [parser] I use is far to slow_”. It's actually pretty hard to make a parser slower than the serial stream that feeds it.

Comment: @Edgar Bonet Sorry, what I mean, I use the Serial0event Interrupt and after receiving the CR I parsed the input line. I did that in a most unconvienient way as described in the question. So now I an searching for a new (smarter) way to do it.

Comment: DARN, I have just found out, that SERIAL_EVENT IS NOT the same as Interrupt , so I have to rewrite all my code.  (#¤&%¤%&¤%#¤)..  So I will redraw this question  (if possible) and come back later.   Anyway Thanks for any thoughs and help so far.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to tell you that. SerialXEvent is just a function that gets called between each iteration of `loop()`. If you want to make it properly interrupt driven you will have to scrap the `HardwareSerial` class crutch and write your own UART code.

Comment: One thing I added to the chipKIT version of the Arduino-esque API was to have `Serial.attachInterrupt(...)` so you can intercept the normal ISR for character reception. Maybe something Arduino should think about adding too...